# Not able to import custom library in google colab even after appending module path to sys

Tags: python, python-import, google-colaboratory, python-module

```
!ls /content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/NLP/my_modules
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/NLP/my_modules')
#!cat '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/my_modules/textprocessing.py'
import textprocessing
```

Even after adding custom module path(Where file resides) System is not able to find file and gives following error.

```
textprocessing.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-67d39291e17e> in <module>()
      6 sys.path.append('/content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/NLP/my_modules')
      7 #!cat '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/my_modules/textprocessing.py'
----> 8 import textprocessing

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textprocessing'
```

I've tried almost all possible solutin for given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/my_modules')
```

Or just

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/my_modules")
```